# Multithreaded deletion from a BST with only local locks

Tags: java, multithreading, binary-search-tree, synchronized

While writing a multithreaded implementation of a BST in Java I come to the following problem. This BST should not use a global lock, but lock as little as possible, specfecly only nodes that are being changed (add and remove command). So other threads can be active in the tree as long as they are not trying to change the same nodes as you.
I can't find a way to implement deletion of a node that has 2 children. The normal algorithm says to find the in order successor of the node to be deleted, to put it in place of the deleted node and then deleted the copied node. But this can create an issue for a thread that is in between those two nodes and needed the copied node, after the transfer, the thread will not find the requested node, even though it is in the tree.
Look at the fallowing example: Tread 1 is executing `remove(5)`. It finds and copies the next key (6) to the node and then deletes the node from the copy. But at the same time another thread executing a `contains(6)` command and is waiting on node 8, after the executing node number 6 will no longer be in its path and it would return a false result even though the 6 node is still in the tree.

Illustration of the state before the remove command (blue arrow indicates where the 2<sup>nd</sup> thread is.
[image]

Illustration of the state after the remove command (blue arrow indicates where the 2<sup>nd</sup> thread is.
[image]

How can I overcome this problem without locking the entire tree?

Comment: Why are you using a BST for this requirement?

Comment: @RohitShetty, this is an exercise specifically on creating a multithreading safe BST.

Comment: i guess https://stackoverflow.com/a/54065194/4109972 is an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I used was to have a version number for the BST, and every time that a `remove` is required for a node with two children I increase the version number before deleting the duplicated node.

Then, each operation checks the version number before it starts and if I get a result that indicates that a key was not found, I check if the version number is still the same, if it's not the same I retry the operation.

This means:

- For `remove` and `contains` - if the action failed (meaning that the key was not found) and the version was changed, try again.
- For `insert` - I check the version number, not at the end of the action, but when I am at a leaf and before creating and adding a new node. If I'm about to add a new node it means I didn't find a node with that key, I want to make sure that the key is really not in the tree before changing it and creating a new leaf to prevent a situation where a double key will be added to the tree and then I'll need to redo this by deleting nodes.

Comment: But wouldn’t this require you to honor the lock on a contains? I see how this will work but I don’t know if this is the optimal implementation.

Comment: @RohitShetty, contains runs without engaging any locks as it doesn't write or change anything in the tree. The only thing that needs to be synchronized is the version counter, but there I use atomic operations (Java's `AtomicInteger`).

Answer (score 0):

Synchronize the nodes independently of the BST. This means if you are deleting a node you will need to lock the top most node that is effected and all nodes below it to prevent other threads from reading or modifying those nodes. Unfortunately with a BST this could mean locking the root node depending on the operation, which would effectively prevent any reads from happening.

I believe this would be the fastest implementation for what you are trying to do.

If sorting doesn't matter I'd recommend using a HashMap implementation instead. You'd only need to lock the buckets instead of potentially the entire map.

Answer (score 0):

I would think backing the BST with a hashset might be the way to go here. That way your lookups would be independent of the BST locking and would give you a O(1) on contains.